# Каким ПО можно настроить разный (по времени) битрейт видео?

Tags: видео, конвертер, кодек

Нужно сделать разный битрейт у видео по времени, допустим, начало видео - высокий битрейт, середина - низкий, конец - опять высокий...

В каком конвертере (как запрограммировать?) так можно сделать ВРУЧНУЮ? другими словами, VBR, но не автоматический по содержимому кадра, а заданный вручную по времени.

Comment: Под какую операционную систему вам нужно такое ПО?

Answer (score 0):

Идея неплоха, но... стара. Лет 10 назад так "убивали" титры в конце. Сейчас же, при возросшей мощности ЦП (да, признаться, и при увеличении объемов систем хранения) эта идея умерла: два прохода с выставленными реперами VBR вполне устраивают. И, кстати, титры определяются и кодируются великолепно.

Но, в целом, можно: в некоторых библиотеках h264 вы можете использовать деление на зоны, для каждой зоны указываете настройки квантизаторов или битрейт/коэффициент умножения битрейта.

Например, для x264 командная строка выглядела примерно так:

```
--zones 1000,3500,b=6000 --zones 4000,6500,crf=10
```

Но это было давно. Сейчас я попробовал несколько реализаций библиотек и программ и понял, что в тех, что стоят у меня, это не работает. В AVIDemux, к примеру, вкладка с зонами вообще "серая":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что, если хочется использовать такой подход, смотрите в сторону FFMPEG с библиотекой libx264, но не факт, что любая реализация подойдёт.